# How to change attributes of one instance with a method of another instance in python

Tags: python, oop, getter-setter

I am trying to change the attributes of instances of one class by changing the attributes of another class. However, in some cases, the attributes don't change as intended.

Assume that I have a class Dot that holds the x-coordinate of that dot

```py
class Dot:
    def __init__(self, x = 0):
        self.x = x
```

and another class Cloth which is initialized with a list of Dot instances

```py
class Cloth:
    def __init__(self, dots):
        self.dots = dots
        self._x = [dot.x for dot in dots]

    @property 
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, arr):
        for ii in range(len(arr)):
            self.dots[ii].x = arr[ii]   
        self._x = arr
```

The class Cloth has an attribute x which returns a list with all x-coordinates of the Dot instances and a getter and setter method which allows changing the list of x's. If I now change the list of x-coordinates it works out well

```py
#instantiate list of dots
dots = [Dot(x = 1), Dot(x = 2), Dot(x = 3)]
#instantiate the cloth
cloth = Cloth(dots)

#change all x-coordinates at once
cloth.x = [2, 3, 4]

print(cloth.x) 
#returns [2, 3, 4]
print(cloth.dots[0].x) 
#returns 2
```

However, if I only try to change one x-coordinate, the x-coordinate of that dot instance is not changed as the setter method isn't called

```py
#change one x-coordinate
cloth.x[0] = -1

print(cloth.x) 
#returns [-1, 3, 4]
print(cloth.dots[0].x) 
#still returns 2 instead of -1
```

Is there a way around that issue or is that due to bad design of the classes?

Comment: You would encapsulate this in a method

Comment: Self.x and self.dots are different things, if you want thy to change together why separate them?

Comment: I think what you want is possible with memory views, but it wouldn't be worthy. Just put this behavior in a method and you be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by geckos above, the issue here is the design decision to replicate the data in two places, rather than have your `Cloth` object provide an interface to the data. By copying the data from the `Dot` objects to the `_x` array we confuse the purpose of each class and give ourselves a synchronisation problem.

How about just passing through to the underlying data like this?

```
class Cloth:
    def __init__(self, dots):
        self.dots = dots

    @property
    def x(self):
        return (dot.x for dot in self.dots)

    @x.setter
    def x(self, arr):
        for value, dot in zip(arr, self.dots):
            dot.x = value
```

The jobs of our two classes are now nicely separated. The job of `Dot` is to store the `x` data, and the job of `Cloth` is to provide an interface to that data in an array format.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks! Is there a reason that the getter method returns a generator instead of a list?

Comment: Mostly personal preference. Just because it doesn't bother allocating any memory and because the values are lazily evaluated, so if you don't look at the last 5 we don't waste time getting them.